# Exception Error in Java : How to continue?

Tags: java, oop

Now, here' the problem :

How to add exceptions so that if my value is negative it would return an error.

---

here's my current code.

```
public class Account {

    String name;
    double balance;

    public Account()
    {
      super();
      this.name = null;
      this.balance = 0;
    }

    public Account(String n, double b){
        name = n;
        balance = b;
    }
}
```

did I do things right? so far?

edited to shorten.

Comment: Don't ask us; ask the compiler. Your code as is; would not even compile. Write short pieces of code (that you think should work); run the compiler, read error messages carefully and fix your code. Repeat. Avoids asking here "is this code good" when you could check that in 5 seconds yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, this is what the exercise wants you to do:

```
public class Account {

    /* 
     * If you know about private members, declare them private.
     * Probably you should because the exercise asks for getter and setter.
     */

    /* private */ String name;
    /* private */ double balance;

    public Account() {
        // Useless: Java calls automatically the superclass constructor.
        // super(); 

        /*
         * These are useless too, because Java initializes the class
         * members to 0, false and null.
         * However, this is what the exercise is asking you to do.
         */

        name = null;
        balance = 0;
    }

    public Account(String name, double balance) {
        // take advantage of setters
        setName(name);
        setBalance(balance);
    }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        if (balance < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("balance must be non-negative.");
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public double getBalance() { return balance; }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, the reason why I did not make those private is because I needed to add another class which accesses that. I did not give the whole project to avoid people of thinking I'm asking them to make my homework lol.

Comment: Here's another fragment of the big problem --                                          Create another method named withdraw, with a double parameter, that deducts the value of the
parameter from your balance field. Make sure that there is enough balance left to make the withdrawal
(balance should never be negative). The withdraw method should return the amount of balance left.
Define a subclass of Account named CurrentAccount, which has an additional field named
numberOfCheques (type int). Create a default constructor that sets the value of numberOfCheques to 0,
name to null, and balance to 0.

Comment: If you add another class you can use setters and getters to access members. Look at this (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables) question to understand why using private members is much better than the direct access.

Comment: ty, I asked another question regarding my program lol. but thanks, done accepting.

Comment: I edited the setBalance method. I forgot to set the balance after checking it.

Answer (score 1):

1 . Create new Exception class like `NegativeBalanceException`

2 . Validate `balance` from the place where you are calling `Account(String n, double b)`. If its -ve then throw `NegativeBalanceException` and right a catch block to handle it

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to call `super();` in your default constructor since you don't have superclass defined (at least I don't see that it `extends` something) and this method will call constructor from superclass.

Comment: Your "answer" should go in as comment - it is a helpful piece of information, but it does not answer his question.

Comment: @Jägermeister Totally agree but unfortunately I don't have yet enough repo to comment posts. I tried to add as comment, I swear. :)

Comment: You need 50 reputation points to create comments. To gain them either ask good question, answer question (real answers ;P) or edit posts to improve them. Posting comments as an answer won't help you, though (as you can see on the downvote).

Comment: @Tom I know it and understand, thx. ;)
Just tried to help. :(
Other point is that question is "did I do things right? so far?"
So I hope at least partially I've answered it. :)

Comment: @Klever Sorry, that is the thing that I keep forgetting. And you are right, answering parts of the question is OK, but if so, your answer should say. And to be honest, explicitly using super() ... which is called anyway is like the smallest of problems here ;-)